# Why same menu entry does not work when grub is installed with `--uefi-secure-boot` option?

Tags: boot, grub, efi

My laptop with `Secure boot` disabled and enabled `CSM support`.
I installed grub onto my USB stick with `--no-uefi-secure-boot` options:
`sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --no-uefi-secure-boot --recheck --removable --efi-directory=/mnt --boot-directory=/mnt/boot -v /dev/sdf`
My next `grub` menu entry loads LM21.1 from `.iso` without any problem:

```
menuentry 'Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon' --class linux --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    set isofile="/iso/linuxmint-21.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso"
    search --no-floppy --set=root --file $isofile
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${isofile} quiet splash ---
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

But when I install grub onto my USB stick with `--uefi-secure-boot` option:
`sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot --recheck --removable --efi-directory=/mnt --boot-directory=/mnt/boot -v /dev/sdf`

Same menu entry fails to load LM21.1 from `.iso`:
[image]

Still if I manually input next command into grub console, `.iso` file loaded successfully:
[image]

What is the problem with my menu entry when `grub` was installed with `--uefi-secure-boot` option?

**UPD**
I suppose `search` command does not set root, so `loopback` command does not find `.iso`. But *why*?